# Storing a multi line file of ints into an array

Tags: java, arrays, tcp

So I have to read a multi-line text file that contains integers. The text file structure would look something like this:

```
1 5 99 3 5 6 
2 6 93 2 5 12 4 5
22 3 44 5
```

As you can see there is a space between each integer. What my program is suppose to do is read in these integers, store them in a data structure(I chose an array) and then manipulate the numbers in a way(I have to find the largest prime below the number if the number is not a prime).

Here's my code:

```
private void processRequest() throws Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(
                new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while(in.hasNextLine()){
            String[] arr = in.nextLine().split(" ");
            int[] intarr = new int[arr.length];

            for(int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++){
                intarr[i] = Integer.parseInt(arr[i]);
                if (prim(intarr[i]) == true){
                    out.println(intarr[i] + " ");

                }else{

                    while (!prim(--intarr[i])){
                    }
                    out.println(intarr[i] + " ");
                }
            }           


            in.close();
            out.close();
            socket.close();
        }
    }
```

My output when running this is everything works for the first line of the text file but after the first line all subsequent lines are null. 
For example:

```
3 7 11 17
null 
null
```

I have another class that is sending the lines of the text file to my processRequest class above and it is sending all the lines with the correct Integers(I ran some tests to make sure). So something is happening in my processRequest class that is causing all lines after line 1 to be null. Anyone have an idea of what's causing this problem?

Comment: What do you mean *"all subsequent lines are null"*? Do you get a `NullPointerException`? If so, show us the stacktrace. If not, change question text to say what you actually get. In short, edit question and clarify it.

Comment: Why do you have an `int` array when you never use it? You might as well just have an `int value`.

Comment: Sorry (edited above), and no I don't get a null pointer exception. I use the int array in the for loop to store the numbers from the string array and then perform my prime method on the int array.

Comment: Are you not closing your streams too early?  Move them outside the while loop?

Comment: If you fixed your indentations, the problem is closing streams too early would be more apparent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, and as @Ian pointed out correctly, is that you are closing your `InputStreamReader`, `PrintStream` and `Socket` a little too early.

What you can instead do is

```
while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    //your logic
}
in.close();
out.close();
socket.close();
```

Hope this helps.